# Is there a way to alter arguments in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

In lisp, I can pass an argument to a function and have it altered within the function. (AKA destructive functions). However, in Clojure, I've read somewhere that it is not permissible to alter the given arguments within that same function. For example:

```
(defn add-two-lists [list1 list2]
  (for [n (range (count list1))]
    (+ (nth list1 n) (nth list2 n))))
```

This is a normal function and its output is the addition of the two identical lists. However, I want something like this:

```
(defn add-two-lists [list1 list2 added_list]
  (set! added_list 
       (for [n (range (count list1))]  
          (+ (nth list1 n) (nth list2 n)))))
```

Perhaps my use of `set!` is wrong or misused, and I still get errors. Is there a elegant way to destructively modify arguments in Clojure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [with-local-vars](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/with-local-vars) macro lets you create thread-locally bound vars that you can modify with [var-set](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/var-set). You also have to access the var's value with [var-get](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/var-get), which can be shortened to just @.

```
(defn add-two-lists [list1 list2 added-list]
  (var-set added-list 
           (for [n (range (count list1))]  
             (+ (nth list1 n) (nth list2 n)))))

(with-local-vars [my-list nil]
  (add-two-lists '(1 2 3) '(3 4 5) my-list)
  @my-list)
```

***EDIT:***

On a stylistic note, you could use [map](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/map) to add the two lists without using the nth function to random-access each index in each list:

```
(defn add-two-lists [list1 list2 added-list]
  (var-set added-list (map + list1 list2)))
```

Comment: I chose this answer as the best, as it showed a way to destructively modify arguments. Not only that, but this answer showed how to access the variable after modifying it.

Comment: Interesting thing though: it seems like `var-set` and `reset!` perform the same function in this example. Is there a reason I should use one over the other?

Comment: I don't think you can substitute `reset!` for `var-set` in the example above. If you are comparing this example to Arthur's example then it's pretty simple: you use `reset!` on an [atom](http://clojure.org/atoms) and `var-set` on a [var](http://clojure.org/vars). Vars and atoms are two of Clojure's four mutable data types. The reason I went with a var over an atom is that atoms are designed for concurrency, so I'd try to avoid them in non-concurrent code. But mikera's suggestion of avoiding destructive mutation is still the best advice whenever you can.

Answer (score 12):

Destructive modification is discouraged in Clojure - I would encourage you to find ways to write your code without resorting to destructive updates.

In the spirit of giving a Clojurey solution, I would write your `add-two-lists` function as follows:

```
(defn add-two-lists [list1 list2]
  (map + list1 list2))
```

This has a few advantages:

- It's purely functional
- It's lazy, so you can even add lists of infinite length (try doing that with a destructively updated argument!)
- It's performance is O(n) which is optimal - the versions in the question are actually O(n^2) since `nth` is itself an O(n) operation on lists.
- It's nice and concise :-)

Comment: I really like your solution! But, I am disappointed that destructive updates are discouraged in Clojure. Oh well!

Comment: You can certainly *do* destructive updates if you want to, but destructive updates are fundamentally against the essence of functional programming style. It bugged me at first, but it was worth learning how to live without them - your code will be much cleaner, more maintainable and more robust if you aggressively cut out mutable state.

Answer (score 6):

Clojure Provides several mutable types that would work well in this situation, for instance you could [pass an `atom`](http://clojure.org/atoms) to the function and have it set the value in that atom.

```
(defn add-two-lists [list1 list2 added_list]
  (reset! added_list 
    (for [n (range (count list1))]  
       (+ (nth list1 n) (nth list2 n)))))
```

then after you call this you get the value out of the atom with `@`/`deref`
edit: if efficiency is the goal then using a [transient collection](http://clojure.org/transients) may help

Comment: I doubt this is relevant; the usual reason for a destructive-set here is the efficiency of not consing. Here, Clojure still allocates a new list and just mutates the pointer to it.

Comment: `reset!` seems to work well in this example, as does `var-set` . Is there a reason I should use one over the other?

Answer (score 1):

From the clojure documentation on [set!](http://clojure.org/vars#set)

```
 Note - you cannot assign to function params or local bindings. Only Java fields, Vars, Refs and Agents are mutable in Clojure.
```

Typically in courses where functional languages are chosen, you are encouraged not to use for-loops and assignments.  Instead you should favor recursion and composition of functions.

So if I wanted to add 2 to each element of a list, in an imperative language, I would just do a for loop, but in a functional language, I would use recursion

```
user=> (def add2
  (fn [mylist]
    (if 
      (empty? mylist) 
        nil
        (cons (+ (first mylist) 2) (add2 (rest mylist))))))

user=> (add2 (list 1 2 3))
(3 4 5)
```

Comment: A more Clojure-idiomatic way of doing this is: (def add2 [mylist] (map (partial + 2) mylist))

Comment: Thank you for reminding me the Clojure-way of programming. Sometimes I forget and revert to old ways :)